# How to get specific sentence in a line of a text file?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, text, line

In visual C#, the button I am implementing needs to read a .txt file and check if each line on the text file ends with a certain character, and if it does, it takes the name on that line and prints it to a message box. So far, I have managed to make the condition to check wheter or not the specified character exists at the end of the line, but can't get the name on it, as it is between two sets of numbers. The name is right after the first character on the line and just before a set of numbers start, as they are the ID of the user.

This is my code so far inside the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line, lastchar;
        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"rato.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lastchar= line.Substring(line.Length - 1, 1);
            if (lastchar== "2") MessageBox.Show("Prints the name of the user here");
        }
        file.Close();
    }
```

And this is the text file:

```
1Paulo111.111.111-11addaqwe2
2Rambo425.433-628-43ererssd3
1Momba111.111.111-11asdsad4432
1Mauricio111.111.111-22wwcssfd2
1Saulo111.111.111-11qwe1231231
```

So the button needs to check if the current line ends with '2' and prints the name in the line. The name in the first line, for example, is **Paulo**, and as it ends with "2", "Paulo" would be printed to the messagebox, just as the third and the fourth line. Otherwise, it would skip to the next line.
It would then be printed in the messagebox: "**Paulo, Momba, Mauricio.**"

How can I do this?

Comment: Look up "Regular Expressions"  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = File.ReadLines(filename)
                .Where(line => line.EndsWith("2"))
                .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, @"\p{L}+").Value)
                .ToList();
```

This will return a list containing `Paulo, Momba, Mauricio.`

**PS:** `\p{L}` : Any unicode letter.

Comment: how do I print that?

Comment: @Kankz do you know how to loop a list? (for ex., `for`, `foreach` etc.....)

Comment: @Kankz forget it. Since there are more complex things like linq and regex involved in this answer....Maybe you want to read this answer a few months later...

Comment: Please, man, this is the only missing part on my project and the deadline is today, can you just tell me what is the code to print each name that ends with '2' on a listbox, one per line? I am new to list, and didn't get the 'var' type, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with both the @L.B's answer and the comment that recommend learning about regular expressions.  That would be a clean approach to your problem.  I am guessing that you are new to C# and so I will provide an answer accordingly.  You should look through the documentation for the [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) class. There are several methods and properties there that you may find useful.  In your case we can look at using the [String.EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) method and the [String.IndexOfAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexofany(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  With these methods we can make some modifications to your code that will make it a little cleaner and easier to understand.

First lets look at this line - the code you have written will create a one character substring for your current string and then you are comparing that with another string.  What you want is to know if the string ends with a '2', so we can use the `EndsWith` method to get this information.

```
lastchar= line.Substring(line.Length - 1, 1);
if (lastchar== "2")
```

Can now be written as:

```
if (line.EndsWith("2"))
```

Now you also want to find the name, this will take two steps. First we need to find the index of the first non-letter character after the name and then we can create a substring and display it in the message box.

```
var numbers = "0123456789.-".ToCharArray();
if(line.EndsWith("2"))
{
    // Get the index of the first non-letter character after the name
    var index = line.IndexOfAny(numbers, 1);
    var name = line.SubString(1, index - 1);
    MessageBox.Show(name); 
}
```

And if you are wondering about the [var](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) type. It is just syntactic sugar that allows the compiler to interpret the type so you don't have to write the type name.

Comment: @Kankz - I don't know. You should step through it with a debugger and see if you are getting the right data, see if it is reading the file, check what the value for the line is, look at the value for name, etc. From the screenshot I can't answer those questions.